# How to get my latest Facebook update from our company page via php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the last 3 updates from our company's Facebook page.

I can see I need to use the 'graph' stuff but the information in the majority of help files etc is for a user not a company page.

I'd like to use PHP and will use cacheing.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook graph API is relatively easy to use, the page of interest to you is : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

The url syntax for posts is https://graph.facebook.com/companypage/feed , however such requests require the usage of an oauth token.
I'd recommend you run through the basic PHP Facebook API examples found with the SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Other tutorials such as http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/ might help.